# ASP. NET MVC Datatables TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am attempting to add a data table in my view but I receive the following error in the console. As of now the data table does not appear. Do I need to add a certain package? I have added reference of data tales in the shared layout.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
at Object.init (Index:157)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Index:191)
at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3362)
at Function.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3582)
at HTMLDocument.completed (jquery-1.12.4.js:3617)
```

Here's my view View:

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-info">Having Trouble</button>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            alert("If your file fails to download it may be because of a special character used in the file name e.g. & or + or = etc. Please change the name and upload again ");
        }
    </script>


    <center>

        @if (@TempData["msg1"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="width:65%">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                @TempData["msg1"]
            </div>
        }

        @if (@TempData["msg"] != null)
        {
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="width:65%">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
                @TempData["msg"]
            </div>
        }


        <h2>Attachments- Job ID: @Session["IdSes"]</h2>



        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "AttachmentsUser", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            <fieldset class="form-horizontal" style="width:70%">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4"> <input type="file" name="photo" style="color:black" /><br /> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-warning" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div><br /></div>
            </fieldset>
        }



        <div class="panel panel-default list-panel" id="list-panel">

            <div class="panel-body">
                <table id="file_list" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:70%;color:#0057a4"></table>
            </div>
        </div>

    </center>



    @section Scripts
   {
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var assetListVM;

            $(function () {

                assetListVM = {
                    dt: null,

                    init: function () {

                        dt = $('#file_list').DataTable({
                            "serverSide": true,
                            "processing": true,
                            "ajax": {
                                "url": "@Url.Action("GetFiles","AttachmentsUser")",
                                "data": function (d) {
                                    d.s = $('input[type=search]').val();
                                }
                            },
                            "columns": [
                                { "title": "FileName", "data": "file_name", "searchable": true },
                                {
                                    "title": "Actions",
                                    "data": "file_name",
                                    "searchable": false,
                                    "sortable": false,
                                    "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                                        return '<a href="@Url.Action("Download","AttachmentsUser")?file=' + data + '" class="download">Download</a> | <a href="@Url.Action("Delete","AttachmentsUser")?file=' + data + '" class="delete">Delete</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                            ],

                        });
                    },

                    refresh: function () {
                        dt.ajax.reload();
                    }
                }

                $('body').on('keyup', 'input[type=search]', function () {
                    assetListVM.refresh();
                });
                // initialize the datatables
                assetListVM.init();
            });

        </script>
    }
```

How do I go about fixing this error? It's a friends piece of code and it works on their project so I think it might be a package I need but I am unsure.

Shared View:

```
    <div class="body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />

    <footer align="center">
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - LotusWorks</p>

    </footer>

</div>

@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Bundle Config:

```
  public class BundleConfig
{
    // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
               "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
        //css  
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/cssjqryUi").Include(
               "~/Content/jquery-ui.css"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/datatables").Include(
        "~/Scripts/DataTables/jquery.dataTables.min.js",
        "~/Scripts/DataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/datatables").Include(
                  "~/Content/DataTables/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"));
    }
```

Comment: `$(...).DataTable is not a function`-this means datatable js files are not available in this page. Check it properly.

Comment: You need to show the layout template - where is the script section rendered and where are the datatables scripts included?  But it sounds like you are either running the scripts section before you include the js or you are not including the datatables js files at all

Comment: @TanvirArjel Okay, so I just need to add js files to the page?

Comment: @Conor8630 `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables")` this should render your datatable related js files to all pages.

Comment: @Pete I've added shared layout to the question. Forgive me im still new to this. would I add them to the shared layout or the view itself? Its the only page using datatables so I guess on the view itself

Comment: @TanvirArjel Yes I have that in my shared layout. Where would I add the js script files in the view?

Comment: @Conor8630 Share your `BundleConfig.cs` file code!

Comment: @TanvirArjel Thanks, I actually just checked and added the datatables script! It Worked!!

Comment: @TanvirArjel If you answer I'll Accept it as correct

Comment: Are you using @Layout in your View? I cannot see that? Where did you add the line to make it work?

Comment: @Conor8630 it actually was `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/datatables")` instead of `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/DataTables")`, isn't it?

Comment: You should bundle all your files into one bundle (that's the point of bundling - make less requests to the server to speed up the load speed of the page)

Comment: @TanvirArjel I just never added them to the bundle config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $(...).DataTable is not a function

This means `datatable` related `js` files are not available in this page. Please somehow make sure that `datatable` related required `js` files are available on that page where you are calling `DataTable()` function. Then error should go away.